# Works fine in Visual Studio, fails to compile on G++ 9.2

Tags: c++, visual-studio, g++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

The following code compiles fine with the latest version of Visual Studio Comumnity 16.5.4 configured to use the latest version of the C++ standard however it fails to compile on G++ 9.2 with a very cryptic and unhelpful error message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

namespace Aux {
    template <std::size_t INDEX, typename TYPE>
    struct TypeValue {
        static TYPE get(std::in_place_index_t<INDEX>);
    };

    template <std::size_t INDEX, typename... TYPES>
    struct TGetType;

    template <std::size_t INDEX, std::size_t... INDICES, typename... TYPES>
    struct TGetType<INDEX, std::index_sequence<INDICES...>, TYPES...>
        : TypeValue<INDICES, TYPES>... {
        using TypeValue<INDICES, TYPES>::get...;
        using Type = decltype(get(std::in_place_index_t<INDEX>()));
    };
}

template <std::size_t INDEX, typename... TYPES>
struct TGetType {
    static_assert(INDEX < sizeof...(TYPES));
    using Type = typename Aux::TGetType<INDEX, std::index_sequence_for<TYPES...>, TYPES...>::Type;
};

template <std::size_t INDEX, typename... TYPES>
using GetType = typename TGetType<INDEX, TYPES...>::Type;

template <std::size_t INDEX, typename... TYPES>
inline constexpr auto get_type = GetType<INDEX, TYPES...>();

int
main() {
    using T = GetType<1, int, double, bool>;
}
```

Here's the error message:

```
C:\Users\joaom\Dropbox\++A\tests\gcc-err.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct Aux::TGetType<1, std::integer_sequence<long long unsigned int, 0, 1, 2>, int, double, bool>':
C:\Users\joaom\Dropbox\++A\tests\gcc-err.cpp:24:8:   required from 'struct TGetType<1, int, double, bool>'
C:\Users\joaom\Dropbox\++A\tests\gcc-err.cpp:28:7:   required by substitution of 'template<long long unsigned int INDEX, class ... TYPES> using GetType = typename TGetType::Type [with long long unsigned int INDEX = 1; TYPES = {int, double, bool}]'
C:\Users\joaom\Dropbox\++A\tests\gcc-err.cpp:35:40:   required from here
C:\Users\joaom\Dropbox\++A\tests\gcc-err.cpp:17:28: error: cannot convert 'in_place_index_t<1>' to 'in_place_index_t<2>'
   17 |   using Type = decltype(get(std::in_place_index_t<INDEX>()));
      |                         ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
C:\Users\joaom\Dropbox\++A\tests\gcc-err.cpp:7:19: note:   initializing argument 1 of 'static TYPE Aux::TypeValue<INDEX, TYPE>::get(std::in_place_index_t<_Idx>) [with long long unsigned int INDEX = 2; TYPE = bool]'
    7 |   static TYPE get(std::in_place_index_t<INDEX>);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

I've installed G++ through https://nuwen.net/mingw.html and it came with the following configuration:

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/program\ files/mingw-w64/mingw-17.1-without-git/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/9.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../src/configure --enable-languages=c,c++ --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --disable-multilib --prefix=/c/temp/gcc/dest --with-sysroot=/c/temp/gcc/dest --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-verbose --disable-nls --disable-shared --disable-win32-registry --with-tune=haswell --enable-threads=posix --enable-libgomp
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.0 (GCC)
```

Haven't tried yet with Clang since the latest version of Visual Studio C++ libraries aren't yet compatible with Clang:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\include\concepts:16:2: error: Despite the presence of some Clang-related bits, this header currently does not support Clang. You can define _SILENCE_CLANG_CONCEPTS_MESSAGE to silence this message and acknowledge that this is unsupported.
#error Despite the presence of some Clang-related bits, this header currently does not support Clang. \
```

Is my code standard compliant or am I relying on MSC extended behaviour? I really don't see anything strange or wrong with it, and more complex cases of metaprogramming similar to that one seems to be working fine on Visual Studio.

Comment: Looks like problem is just in gcc.
clang 11.0 compiled it fine. https://wandbox.org/permlink/EasMxJAI1P08GrE9

Comment: As a work around, you can make `TypeValue` not inherited and a helper class instead. I think it has to do with type completeness and the lack of guarantees around that, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: @user975989, can you give me a concrete example of that approach, please? One of the advantages of my code is that getting a type has a O(1) complexity with minimal template instantiations